# Cannot get link from missing tbody tag (web scraping)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the link in order to download the pdf in tbody tag, but the tag didn't show up after getting the HTML source code. How to get those links. Here's the website: https://www.nexeoplastics.com/types/plastics-product-finder?s=TPU

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get("https://www.nexeoplastics.com/types/plastics-product-finder?s=TPU")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

table = soup.find_all(id="maintable")
print(table)
```

The results only shows thead, but not tbody, can anyone whelp me to get the link?

Answer (score 0):

Content is provided by an ajax call - to check that open your developer tools of your browser and take a closer look into the network section. You could use `selenium` to render the page like a browser and work on the drivers page_source or go with the ajay call like this:

```
import requests

r=requests.get("https://www.nexeoplastics.com/product-ajax-search/?s=TPU&_=1657516141911").json()

for item in r['data']:
    print(item)
```

Output

```
{'id': '<label class="checkbox-custom"><input type="checkbox" id="row-checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label>', 'supplier_td': '<a href="suppliers/europe/wanhua/">Wanhua Chemical Group Co., Ltd.</a>', 'product': 'Wanthane®', 'grade': 'WHT-1190', 'link': '<a href="types/plastics-database-datasheet?id=150219&product=Wanthane%C2%AE&grade=WHT-1190"><img src="/assets/tpl/img/dowloaddocument.png" /></a>', 'generic': 'Thermoplastic Polyurethane Elastomer (Polyester)', 'density': '1.19,ASTM D792', 'flowrate': '', 'impact': '', 'tensilestrength': '', 'flexuralstrength': '', 'modulus': '', 'rockwell': '', 'dtul264': '', 'dtul66': '', 'region': 'Europe'}
{'id': '<label class="checkbox-custom"><input type="checkbox" id="row-checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label>', 'supplier_td': '<a href="suppliers/europe/wanhua/">Wanhua Chemical Group Co., Ltd.</a>', 'product': 'Wanthane®', 'grade': 'WHT-1195', 'link': '<a href="types/plastics-database-datasheet?id=150220&product=Wanthane%C2%AE&grade=WHT-1195"><img src="/assets/tpl/img/dowloaddocument.png" /></a>', 'generic': 'Thermoplastic Polyurethane Elastomer (Polyester)', 'density': '1.20,ASTM D792', 'flowrate': '', 'impact': '', 'tensilestrength': '', 'flexuralstrength': '', 'modulus': '', 'rockwell': '', 'dtul264': '', 'dtul66': '', 'region': 'Europe'}
...
```

To get the download link:

**Note:** *walrus operator requires python 3.8 or higher*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get("https://www.nexeoplastics.com/product-ajax-search/?s=TPU&_=1657516141911").json()

for item in r['data']:
    if e:=BeautifulSoup(item['link']):
        print('https://www.nexeoplastics.com/'+e.a.get('href'))
```

Python version < 3.8:

```
...
for item in r['data']:
    if BeautifulSoup(item['link']):
        print('https://www.nexeoplastics.com/'+BeautifulSoup(item['link']).a.get('href'))
```

Comment: But I don't see the <href> inside the <tbody> and how am I getting it. I'm now trying selenum

Comment: there is no `<tbody>` it is stored in a `JSON` structur, added an example to go for the download link

Comment: Hi, sry for taking so long, I can't run the code you gave 'e:=BeautifulSoup(item['link']):' to get the link. I was confused because I inspect the website and it's in tbody

Comment: What does *can't run the code you gave* means? Any error message? Concerning your confusion - How or better what do you inspect? Is the `tbody` in your `response` or `soup`? Check the intro to my answer again.